# How can I remove binlog files after disabling bin-logging in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, binlog

In mysql 8, what is a recommended and safe way of removing old bin logs other than with "PURGE BINARY LOGS..."

After disabling binary logging on mysql (with skip-log-bin) I have 500GB of unneeded bin logs.  I have no immediate plans of reenabling it, but don't want to break anything if I decide to use it in the future.  Is it safe to manually remove them (ie., *rm binlog.xxxx*) and truncate the index file (*echo > binlog.index*) perhaps?
Since bin-log is disabled,  the documented and typically recommended purge commands are unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually removing the files, you should use  `purge` statement to purge all binlogs which is safe.

`show binary logs`  -- Pick up the last binary log & purge it.

Yes, you can do `rm binlog.XX` & remove index file also. This is last option used when nothing works.

But before manually removing that please verify that below statement returns empty rows.

`show master status;`