# How to delete the remaining binlog files after disabling binlog in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I use [this solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41054/171650) to delete my `binlog` before I disable the log. After I disabled it, I tested the below commands to remove the remaining files, but without success.(The purpose of deleting is to save space.)

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'binlogname';
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE 'datetimestamp';
```

My question is: Is it safe to remove them manually? (I found those questions [question1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314912/how-can-i-remove-binlog-files-after-disabling-bin-logging-in-mysql-8) and [question2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315256/is-it-safe-to-manually-delete-binary-logs-after-disabling-it) which are similar to mine but the answer is uncertain to me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my post from [Apr 26, 2013 21:57](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41050/is-it-safe-to-delete-mysql-bin-files/41054#41054)

> Please do not just delete them in the OS.

First you run the purge like this

```
FLUSH BINARY LOGS;
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW();
```

Then, go disable it.

Once you disable binary logging, the `PURGE BINARY LOGS` will say nothing.

If you run `SHOW BINARY LOGS`, you should see

```
mysql> show binary logs;
ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging
mysql>
```

I stated the reasons for not doing it while mysqld is running in my old post.

Comment: thanks, It works 100%. All the heavy log has gone, only `binlog.index` and `binlog.last` remains with size less than 1KB; Which I think they should remain, and there are no ways to eliminate them.

Comment: Now that binary logging is disabled, you can go and delete them manually

Answer (score -1):

Just remove binlog.**** files from /var/lib/mysql, with binlog.index files and restart mysql. So it will create binlog.index again and fix

Comment: The OP is saying that they cant delete the files!!!